# How to define a custom code style for C/C++ to be shared with others?

Tags: c-mode, style

I have my own code style setup in my `init.el` file, but would like to publish it for other developers to use. Is there a good template to use so projects can share their C/C++ code style between developers?

---

Notes:

- Having this as a separate package may be too much hassle/overhead.
- Including a file and then referencing the style by name might be the way to go.

Comment: Certainly not the answer you expect, but you can still use https://github.com/sonatard/clang-format . Code style is then defined by  a .clang-format file which is easily sharable.

Comment: Even in this case, you want emacs to follow code style on a basic level - not to require re-formatting on every new line or inserting braces, even if you're running clang-format on file-save.